# Gunicorn cannot find modules

Tags: python, django, docker, gunicorn

I am trying to run a django-docker image via gunicorn. However, gunicorn does not find my modules.

I tried to use gunicorn in a venv. (adding `CMD exec source venv/bin/activate`  in the Dockerfile.) This is also not working.
What am i doing wrong?

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.7
MAINTAINER Jasper
ADD . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD exec gunicorn bomt_project.wsgi:application --preload --bind 
0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3
```

I expect the server to be running on port 8000. The output however is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widget_tweaks'`

Comment: What is the content of `requirements.txt`?

Comment: ````django_tables2
django-filter
python-dotenv
psycopg2 
Django==2.2
gunicorn==19.9.0````

This is the requirements.txt

Comment: So how do you want to import `widget_tweaks` if you don't install it?

Comment: wow. That was the problem. Such a dumb fault :shame